# MSVC17 Linking application with runtime statically, still getting missing dll error

Tags: visual-studio, static-linking, msvcrt

I set /MT flag to have my c++ application statically linked with C runtime, so I don't have to worry about redistributing the runtime, however, upon launch I get an error message saying missing "Api-ms-win-core-version-l1-1-0.dll". How do I compile my application so that its completely independent of any runtime etc?

Build Environment: MSVC 2017, windows 10 SDK
Compile and Test machine: 64-Bit Windows 7

Comment: It is an operating system DLL, you can't build a C++ program without a dependency on the OS.  Ensure that Windows Update gets a chance to update that machine.

Comment: @HansPassant Test machine has all Windows Updates applied. I thought the whole point of static linking with run-time was that there won't be any missing dll errors? Btw, when I link the program using MD flag, then it runs without any issue. For this application, I have to deliver a single executable that should just run on XP SP3+ systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selected answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a28331ae-19a3-4a34-b3ba-1e8fd4430375/missing-apimswincore-dlls) helped me solve my problem. In short, you can't link with any of the *api-ms-win-core** libraries, you should link with appropriate libraries listed for APIs in the msdn. The *api-ms-win-core** libraries are used indirectly by the OS, that's why they show up as missing -  when in reality the appropriate windows .lib need to be linked.

In my case, I used depends to figure out which API libraries were missing then looked up the appropriate .lib files in msdn and added those in "additional dependencies". Problem solved.

FYI, /MT flag is working as expected, I don't have to redistribute c-runtime etc.